# Как лучше идентифицировать Access базы?

Tags: c#, .net, access, office

Делаю службу, которая должна работать с Access базами.

Пользователь может загружать новые базы в хранилище, скачивать имеющиеся базы из хранилища и изменять их, а потом возвращать.

На каждую Access базу создается запись в БД службе, где указывается путь и место хранение.

Собственно вопрос: Как мне лучше организовать идентификацию Access баз, что бы понимать :"Так вот эта база новая, на нее я создам строчку, а вот эта база старая, ее я должен обновить" ?

По названию идентифицировать- не вариант.

У меня есть идея создавать скрытую таблицу и туда прописывать Id из БД.

В таком случае придется обращаться к interopt(Для создания скрытой таблицы), а я его недолюбливаю

Может есть что-нибудь по лучше, что можно использовать для идентификации?

Comment: а в записи в "БД службы" хранить данный флажок можно?

Comment: База регистрируется в службе. Пользователь может скачать бд, внести правки и загрузить в хранилище через службу. Вот на этом месте мне нужно понимать база зарегистрирована в службе или нет.

Comment: А чем вообще отличаются базы в службе (структура, разные пользователи и т.д.)? т.е. например человек скачал базу, сохранил под 2 названиями, внес разные правки и загружает в хранилище, с точки зрения службы это 1 база или разные?

Comment: Если базе присутствует идентификатор, которым помечаются базы, то одна. В этом случае служба заменит базу в хранилище на более новую версию.

Comment: про идентификатор - это понятно, я с точки зрения логики службы, т.е. разные базы в службе - это могут быть одинаковые по структуре базы но с разными данными, или это должны быть разные по структуре базы. Я это к чему: к примеру если разные базы будут с разной структурой, то можно хранить у себя хеш структуры базы, например md5, и проверять его при загрузке

Comment: Юзер может скачать базу, изменить ее структуру и загрузить обратно. Тогда на сервере службы, база обновится. Так что структура- не вариант. Можно ли на Access какую-нибудь подпись ?

Comment: т.е. база даже с измененной структурой но с тем же идентификатором будет для службы одной и тойже базой? тогда юзер и любую подпись может поменять, раз он спокойно может менять данные и структуры

Comment: Вопрос в том, как скрыть от юзера эту подпись.

Comment: От чего предполагается защищаться? Какая может быть выгода пользователю от введения системы в заблуждение?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать для разных юзеров разные каталоги, в которых будет лежать в каждом каталоге база. Т.к. с одним каталогом может возникнуть проблема конкурирующего доступа к **БД**. Также разные каталоги (каждый пользователь будет видеть только свой каталог) обеспечат уникальность базы в пределах одного пользователя, т.е. идентификатором будет имя каталога. Различие в базе необходимо сравнивать с помощью хеш-сумм (к примеру **md5**). Внутри службы как раз будет идентификация базы по имени каталога, принадлежащего пользователю.

В решении присутствует ряд подводных камней, от конкурирующего доступа до проблемы нехватки места при большой базе, т.к. будет копия файла для каждого пользователя, но общую проблему автора это решит.

Comment: А как затем приводить зоопарк БД к общему виду, синхронизировать то есть? @iluxa1810 может стоит перейти к клиент-серверным СУБД?
UPD открыл для себя репликацию :)

Comment: В режиме карусели опрашивать каждую изменившуюся базу. Вопрос был конкретно про Access. Естественно, что Access мало пригодна для многопользовательского режима работы. Но даже в моём примере можно каждому пользователю давать только ту информацию, которая касается только его. Соответственно и заполняться будет только определённая часть. Своего рода оффлайн версия.
P.S.: Да, именно репликация.

Comment: По подробнее на счет репликации.

Comment: Что конкретно интересует? Здесь будет так называемая асинхронная репликация со всеми её проблемами. В каждый момент времени будет синхронизироваться только одна пользовательская база с центральной базой.